# I get the .any or .all error and I don't know what the formatting means

Tags: python, numpy

I simply want it so when the temperature is above 15.5 AND there is hail I want hail to equal 3 and otherwise I just want hail to equal hail.

```
hail = np.where((hail > 0 and tmp > 15.5).all, 3, hail)
```

My error is:

```
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Looks like there are two problems in the above code: 1) `and` means it's converting the entire series to a boolean, then doing the and. You probably want `&`, which does elementwise and. 2) Using `(...).all()` means that you're turning the entire series into a single boolean, which means that `np.where()` will do the same thing to every element. Probably not what you want. I suggest changing this to `hail = np.where((hail > 0 & tmp > 15.5), 3, hail)`

Comment: @Nick, you need more (), `(hail > 0) & (tmp > 15.5)`

Comment: The duplicate has a lot of answers, so it can be hard to identify which applies to your case.  This ambiguity error arises when ever you try to use arrays in a context that expects a scalar True/False value.  `and` is one such case. Due to operator precedence, you want to group the `>` tests to evaluate first, and then use the `&` (or `logical_and` to combine them, giving the `where` a boolean array as condition.